# Getting a field with name "value" from a JS object

Tags: javascript, console

I currently have a JS object with the following structure:

```
{ id: "12", name: "john", value: "55" }
```

In order to access the id or name of this object i can simply print it with:

```
console.log(myObject.id)
```

or

```
console.log(myObject.name)
```

Both of these will successfully print the id or name of the object, however if I attempt to call:

```
console.log(myObject.value)
```

I am getting the result `undefined`. I am assuming this is because it is trying to get the value of the object, rather than access the field named value. How can I access the field named value?

Comment: can you create a [mre] of your issue? Preferably using a [code-snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)?

Comment: Tried it: works for me: `myObject={id: "12", name: "john", value: "55"}`, `console.log(myObject.id)` resulted in: "12", `console.log(myObject.name)` resulted in: "john", and `console.log(myObject.value)` resulted in: "55".

Comment: myObject["value"]